# Resetting the success or failure messages on html form

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page in which  success or failure messages will be printed on form submit.
But when clicking on the reset button, values stored in the fields get reset but it does not disappear the message which is displayed.


I am using a reset button which on clicking invokes a javascript function for resetting all the input fields

Is there anything that can be added in the script to reset the message as well??
Please help...

Comment: Provide your code you tried .

Answer (score 0):

you should probably show some of the code on how you are doing this, but just in case, if the message you add looks something like this:

```
const errorSpan = document.getElementById('#errorMsg')
if (error) {
    errorSpan.innerText = error
}
```

Then on the reset function you could just do:

```
errorSpan.innerText = ''
```

In the future try and be more descriptive on the example you are doing.